# Formatting a JSON-Like String Without External Library

Tags: java

How can I go about formatting this string to give me the "gs" value?

```
{"status":1,"gs":"a2fdee457d64cd48f399f1a9fea4a977","user_type_id":1,"uid":-980}
```

I have looked at many of the similar questions on stack overflow, however, most suggest to use an external library. I do not want to use an external library because I am using this for libgdx, and an external library will just create unnecessary complications.

Comment: this looks like a job for regex

Comment: Do you mean "formatting" or "parsing"?

Comment: @HotLicks I am trying to get this value "a2fdee457d64cd48f399f1a9fea4a977" and set that to a variable.

Comment: (If that's as bad as it gets you can get along pretty well with `indexOf` and `substring`, or, a little more powerful, `split`.)

Comment: Is your "JSON like" string actually JSON, or can we make assumptions, no nested objects, for example?

Comment: @Andreas There are no nested objects. It is not actually JSON either, its just formatted as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know specifically that you are looking for the value after `"gs"`, then you can simply do the following:

```
// String input = [string in your question];
input = input.substring(input.indexOf("\"gs\"") + "\"gs\"".length()); // we move past the ':'
input = input.substring(input.indexOf('"') + 1); // move past the first '"' after "gs"
String gs = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('"'));
```

And now `gs` contains the string `a2fdee457d64cd48f399f1a9fea4a977`.

Comment: But note that JSON allows non-significant "whitespace" between tokens, so the above is not "robust" in the face of changes on the sending side.

Comment: @HotLicks You're right. I modified my answer to accommodate that.